# Modal within modal when opened, close first only - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created bootstrap modal within modal and first open the main modal and then opening the child modal within the modal, but when I close it should first close the child modal and then parent modal separately, Currently its closing all together.

Also, I am trying to close it in dynamic way, as the parent/child modal ID may get changed.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Main Modal - Parent
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" id="mymodal-inner" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-inner">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
        <!-- Modal Inner -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-inner" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                Inner Modal - Child
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want when you click on inner modal close button it should close the inner modal and when you click on outer modal close button it should close the outer modal...right?

Comment: Yes right this is what I am looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the **`#myModal-inner`** div outside the **`#mymodal`** div. Check the snippet below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Main Modal - Parent
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" id="mymodal-inner" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-inner">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
        <!-- Modal Inner -->


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-inner" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Inner Modal - Child
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thats great! I was trying to write JS to handle this..but worked. thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: One problem I found with this solution is when we close the child modal then we cannot scroll the parent modal. The problem here is when we open the first modal the class ".modal-open .modal" is being applied to both parent and child modal and when we close the child this class also removes from parent ".modal-open .modal". this class contains overflow-y: auto and as the child modal closes the class also removed from parent therefor we cannot able to scroll top or bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the code that you have given, Only i have triggered the Child Modal Close via jQuery. Please check

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Main Modal - Parent 
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" id="mymodal-inner" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-inner">
                    Launch demo modal
                </button>
                <!-- Modal Inner -->
                <div class="modal fade childModel" id="myModal-inner" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close closeChild" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Inner Modal - Child
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default closeChild">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="parentid" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    jQuery(document).on("click", "button.closeChild", function (e) {
        jQuery('.childModel').modal('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its working but I prefer to go with solution by @Bhuwan Bhatt since it doesnt require any custom JS. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution to the scrolling glitch, when the first modal is closed, use this `style="max-height: 1000px; overflow-y auto;` means externally we are adding scrolling to that particular modal.

Example:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
  style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: auto;">
```